# NextJS and Django Project Deploy

Tags: reactjs, django, next.js, django-rest-framework, vercel

Does anyone know how to deploy the django+nextJs app
currently, my frontend is running on localhost:3000 and Django at 127.0.1:8000 and its is working perfectly on my local machine
I want to deploy it on a live server anyone who knows how to do this
I have deployed the next app on Vercel (https://cropsight-dusky.vercel.app/)
but it will not move further from login unless Django is also running simultaneously.

I have checked it If the nextJs project is running on Vercel and my Django is running locally then the request from front end will come to me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your deployed client to point to localhost, you can tunnel your localhost django server using tools like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com).